# Convert fraction into decimal

Tags: fractions

Trying to help my daughter with a question for her maths that has got me stuck...wish I was better at maths!

Convert the fraction 27/50 into decimal

Could someone please help me with this question.

Comment: and I wish I was the president

Comment: I feel sure you know a calculator will do that conversion to decimal.  Perhaps you are asking about understanding the process or looking for a mental shortcut, but little you wrote suggests you merely wanted others to do your thinking for you, because of the lack of effort demonstrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that our numeration system has basis $10$ so $$\frac{27}{50}=\frac{27\times 2}{50\times 2}=\frac{54}{100}=0.54$$

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{27}{50}=\frac{27*2}{50*2}=\frac{54}{100}=0.54$